# No output in c++ program for big_endian check

Tags: c++

I was experimenting with C++ and I decided to try the is_big_endian code, in much the same way  I would do it in C. However I am getting no output when I try to print out the value of the pointer. I tried both the C and C++ style casts. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (void){
    int num = 1;
    char *ptr = (char *)&num;
    //char *ptr = reinterpret_cast<char *>(&num);

    cout << "Value is: " << *ptr << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`operator<<` sees that you are outputting a `char`, so it prints it as a character, not as a number (it's as if in C you wrote `%c` instead of `%d` in a `printf`); and since `*ptr` will either be 0 or 1, you'll end up in both cases with a non-printable character.

To fix this, cast explicitly `*ptr` to `int`:

```
cout << "Value is: " << int(*ptr) << endl;
```

Comment: Ahh!! That makes perfect sense. Thank you for the help.